# Continous Integration and Cakephp 3.x internationalisation with multiple plugins in project

Tags: php, jenkins, internationalization, continuous-integration, cakephp-3.0

In our use case we're using cake 3's plugins to seperate different front-ends for the same data (simplified explanation) - and because of this, we have a a lot of `__('random_strings'); spreaded out in files in following paths:

1. src/*
2. plugins/plugin_name(s)/*

I'm using the following command to extract the `.pot`files:

`bin/cake i18n extract --app /cake/ --paths src,plugins --merge yes --output /cake/src/Locale  --exclude test,vendors --overwrite --extract-core yes`

We're using Jenkins with an Ant script for bulding our application, and we're about to choose a online web gui for translating these `.pot` files - and it's a requirement that translaters without developer-knowledge can then go into that web gui, translate the files and somehow synchronize the resulting `.po` files back into the git repo.

I'm thinking to have a jenkins job that runs before the current one we have, which only job is to run the script for generating `.pot` files and then commit + push them back into our development branch - and then have the web gui "check" these .po files for each language.

However, this feels kinda hack-ish, and some better solution might exist :-)

Comment: We've just setup an instance of www.poeditor.com - and added our languages, and it takes care (kinda hack'ish) of importing new stuff from `.pot` files to the respective `.po` - althought by far an elegant solution. It works with manual export from Poeditor to github, and they support webhooks too. The webhooks just made 400 commits to our repo though.... 

Anyone have experience with software for A) Getting translations from .pot files - updated languages, making translators translate it and then push the changes back into Git again - please let me know! :-)

Comment: You might look into Weblate. It's got git integration built in.

Comment: Thanks Greg - looks good! I might look into it an some point.. Doesn't have a high usability for non-developers tho :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pulling/pushing translations from our GitHub project 3 times daily w/ POEditor.com's API - but I havn't yet automated the generation of the .pot files, so that's manually for now.

Don't know if we're gonna implement pre-commit git hook, or implement a pre-production build in Jenkins checking it :-)